# Blue Prism does not detect elements in Chrome open tool

Tags: blueprism

Using Application Modeller I indentified some HTML elements on a Chrome web page (for clicking on stuff, fill input fields...)

When my bot clicks 'Attach' button, the Chrome will open the Chrome open tool (where you can browse for files). My problem is that I can't identify elements inside that open tool. I used some writers to type in the path field and file name field the path and the file name, but the bot is acting like the Chrome open tool does not exist. Do you have any idea about how can I make the bot complete those fields?

Answer (score 0):

It's common that browsers (for security, among other reasons) will spawn these file browser windows as separate processes. This means that Blue Prism won't see the resulting window as a part of the same browser.

You'll need to either create a new object to attach directly to the window, or detatch and re-attach to the file chooser window once you've opened it. Attaching by the "Window Title" is usually the quickest and easiest way to target these.

Once you've attached to the file chooser window, you should be able to spy the interface elements there. If you're using the detatch and re-attach functionality within your preexisting Business Object, don't forget to detatch and re-attach to your browser instance once you've completed the required actions in the file chooser window.

Comment: Ok, but how can I attach that object to the window? I mean, my bot clicks the 'Attach' button and the window opens, I guess that in your solution I should open the window every time I'm running the app, but how can I correlate those windows to work as one?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm new in Blue Prism and I don't fully understand how things are going. You're saying that I can use an object as a part of another object?

Comment: As one of esqew suggestions, create a separate object to interact with the popup window. When you click on `Attach` button, call your other object to interact with the popup. I find this approach to be the easiest as i can set the object that interacts with popup window to be a **Windows** object so i don't have to detach and attach within the same object